# how to get window.onload function to work in Jade templating language

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm new to Jade and NodeJS express.  I have a simple web page that loads a jpeg with the div tag.  I want to be able to have a responsive image map with the following html and JS but can't get it to work.

```
<div style="width:100%;">
<img id="img_ID" src="http://pindragon.social/images/landing.jpeg" usemap="#map" border="0" width="100%" alt="" />
```

```
window.onload = function () {
var ImageMap = function (map, img) {
        var n,
            areas = map.getElementsByTagName('area'),
            len = areas.length,
            coords = [],
            previousWidth = 128;
        for (n = 0; n < len; n++) {
            coords[n] = areas[n].coords.split(',');
        }
        this.resize = function () {
            var n, m, clen,
                x = img.offsetWidth / previousWidth;
            for (n = 0; n < len; n++) {
                clen = coords[n].length;
                for (m = 0; m < clen; m++) {
                    coords[n][m] *= x;
                }
                areas[n].coords = coords[n].join(',');
            }
            previousWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
            return true;
        };
        window.onresize = this.resize;
    },
    imageMap = new ImageMap(document.getElementById('map_ID'), document.getElementById('img_ID'));
imageMap.resize();
return;
```

}

Comment: Could you give a bit more details? In a Pug-related question I'd typically expect at least some Pug code: How do you include that script you list in the second snippet in the template? Maybe also motivate why you are using Pug at all - from what I can see here, there is no direct need for it. Lastly, please be more elaborate on _what exactly_ doesn't work as you'd expect it to - is the script simply not called? Or is it called but exhibiting some unexpected behavior?

Comment: That is what I'm asking is for someone to give an example of how to properly include it.  As a new user of Jade, I had no idea it was called Pug even.  Where does it get included in the layout.jade under 'head' I assume.  As a new user it seems like an incredibly bad name 'Pug' since the extensions are still '.jade'  I can load the above code in http://jsfiddle.net/ and see it works, but I can't get it to work using Pug!  I'll add that the spaces or tabs requirement seems incredibly brittle.

Comment: The requirement that 'script.' have no preceding spaces is also a great way to trip up a new user.

Comment: You can include scripts anywhere you like in your template, both in the `head` and in the `body` tags. And yes, Pug/Jade requires any form of indentation to function - that is part of its syntax. If these things don't feel comfortable to you, I'd say you can just as well abandon it and use plain HTML - from what I've seen so far in your question, there is no need for Pug. A plain HTML file with the JS code embedded in `<script>` tags should be sufficient.

Comment: most of my issues seem to be the finicky issue of spaces versus tabs and Vim.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that there are no spaces allowed before the 'script.'
Use spaces or tabs but not both.  Jade/Pug is super finicky about this.
I'm not going to post the code here because it uses tabs and doesn't format.

Place the 'script.' on the line following 'head' in layout.jade and follow it with the window.onload JS properly indented using spaces or tabs.

Place the html as jade tags in index.jade